# Combine Boolean Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I’m trying to create a combine boolean matrix function, using the following code.

```
def AndCombine(array1, array2):
    if array1.shape != array2.shape:
        return 'Matrix size not equal.'
    else:
        Product= np.where(array1==1, True, np.where(array2==1, True, False))
    print (Product)
    return Product
```

The matrices I’m testing to combine are:

```
arr1= np.array([[True, False], [False, True]])
arr2= np.array([[False, True],[True, True]])
```

When I run my `AndCombine(arr1, arr2)` function, I expect to see a product of `[[False, False],[False, True]]`, however the output I receive is `[[True, True],[True, True]]` and I’m unsure as to why this is happening.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the `&` operator?

```
>>> arr1 & arr2
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `&` does bit-wise comparison. `arr1 & arr2` is equivalent to `np.bitwise_and(arr1, arr2)`, although the former is slightly faster.